# How can I use is_archive() in index.php to retrieve specific archive based template in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing a WordPress blog site.

I'm trying to get a specific template according to WordPress conditional tags as written bellow:

```
switch(1):
    case(!is_single() && get_post_type() == 'post'):
        get_template_part('/frontend/template-parts/general');
        break;
    case(is_single() && get_post_type() == 'post'):
        get_template_part('/frontend/template-parts/single/single', get_post_format());
        break;
    case(is_archive()):
        get_template_part('/frontend/template-parts/archives/category');
        break;
endswitch;
```

and, it works fine for first two conditons. But, It's not workig, when I'm trying to get the category.php template located in '/frontend/template-parts/archives/' directory based on is_archive() conditional tag.

How can I set templates like category.php, tag.php, archive.php, author.php dynamically, located on '/frontend/template-parts/archives/' directory based on is_archive() conditional tag placed in index.php as mentioned above.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try Below code.

```
switch(1):
    case(!is_single() && get_post_type() == 'post'):
        get_template_part('/frontend/template-parts/general');
        break;
    case(is_single() && get_post_type() == 'post'):
        get_template_part('/frontend/template-parts/single/single', get_post_format());
        break;
    case(is_archive()):
        get_template_part('/frontend/template-parts/archives/archive');
        break;
    case(is_category()):
        get_template_part('/frontend/template-parts/archives/category');
        break;
    case(is_tag()):
        get_template_part('/frontend/template-parts/archives/tag');
        break;
    case(is_author()):
        get_template_part('/frontend/template-parts/archives/author');
        break;
endswitch;
```

Comment: Thanks, @Bhautik. I've tried it before. But, It's not working.